# No duplicates in listbox vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have a listbox which adds items with a button, every time i click it again adds up those same items which i dont want .
can there be any solution for this in VBA?

Comment: show us the code you already built and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old items before adding new ones, using

```
ListBox1.Clear
```

Comment: The above answer does solve the problem but a message box should be prompting up after clicking once